# Ada: Error in GetRegistryEntry open AdaGIDE

Tags: ada

Yesterday I was using AdaGIDE and all was fine. Today... not so much.

Everytime I attempt to open AdaGIDE this message pops up:

> Error in GetRegistryEntry open AdaGIDE code: 0

I'll click OK then get this:

> Error in GetRegistryEntry query code: 0

Again, click OK and this comes up:

> Not enough environment space

Does anyone have any idea whatsoever what is going on and how to fix it? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but this problem still occurs. For now I'm doing all my Ada homework in the one comp sci lab that has AdaGIDE and I'd love to work on my laptop again. (I'm running Windows 10 if that matters!)

Comment: I don't know but is the drive holding temporary files full by chance?

Comment: why not use gnat for that? afaik AdaGIDE is ancient.

Comment: I would just like to mention that I never did figure out what was going on. I ended up useing the school computers to do my assignments instead.